# How to get Meta Data of native sql query in Slick when there are no records

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am using Playframework Slick module to get the meta data of Native SQL queries. This works fine when there are records returned by the query. But when the query does not return any records I am not able to get the meta data such as column name, type etc.

```
  def getMetaData(query: String): Future[Seq[Seq[(String, String, Int, Int, Int)]]] = db.run {
    val stmt = sql"#$query"
    stmt.as(ResultMeta)
  }

object ResultMeta extends GetResult[Seq[(String, String, Int, Int, Int)]] {
  def apply(pr: PositionedResult) = {
    val resultSet = pr.rs
    val metaData = resultSet.getMetaData
    (1 to pr.numColumns).map { i =>

      (metaData.getColumnName(i), metaData.getColumnTypeName(i),
        metaData.getColumnType(i), metaData.getPrecision(i),
        metaData.getScale(i))
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a different mechanism where I can get the meta data when there are no records returned by the query?

Comment: Why would you need the metadata? Looks like x/y...

Comment: @cchantep well, I am generating a dynamic query based on a json paylaod, and want to send back the columns and types in the response even when the records are empty

Comment: Do you want to introspect the data or do you need something specific to a particular query? If the latter how do you do it in JDBC?